# How to hide div on mouse over of another div?

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs, show-hide

I have HTML something like this:

```
<table>

  <tr>
     <td><div class='record'>Record Link</div></td>
     <td><div class='delete' style='display:none;'>Delete Link</div></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td><div class='record'>Record Link</div></td>
     <td><div class='delete' style='display:none;'>Delete Link</div></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

`Delete Link` is hidden in above HTML. I want to show `Delete Link` when mouseover on its related `record DIV`

After trying some basic tutorials of **prototypejs**, I am able to write following code which is working for me but not completed.

```
document.on('mouseover', 'div.record', function(event, element) {
    event.target.hide(); // testing: it hides the record itself
});
```

Following codes are **not working** for me:

```
$('delete').setStyle({ display: 'block' });
$$('div.delete').setStyle({ display: 'block' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prototype, by setting `$("delete")` you are calling element with id `delete` which i dont see anywhere. 
You need to set the `<div id='delete' style='display:none;'>Delete Link</div>`

and use the following to bind events and start your script unobtrusively,

**EDIT** Since there many div.delete use the $$() selector as follows

```
     document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
     var deleteLinks=$$(".delete");
     for(var i=0;i<deleteLinks.length;i++){

        deleteLinks[i].observe("mouseover",functio(){
          this.setStyle({ display: 'block' });


        }); //bind event

      }
    });
```

If you want to hide on `mouseover` set `display:none` instead of `display:block`
You can also use `visibility:hidden` but that will still occupy space on your html as 
an area portion

Comment: I cant set id because there are many `delete` divs on same page. I think I have to use class for `delete` div

Answer (score 2):

try CSS:

```
table#mytable tr:hover .delete{  /*identify your table for this effect, so as not to affect other tables*/         
    display:block !important;    /* !important is needed for override since */ 
}                                /* you styled "display:none" on element level */
```

what this does is detect hovering on the child from the parent level (CSS does bubbling), and then style the subjected element.